# IBarcodeWriter.Write is gone

Tags: c#, zxing, zxing.net

I had function that was printing barcode fine:

```
public void drawQr(string val)
{

IBarcodeWriter writer = new BarcodeWriter
{
    Format = BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE,
    Options = new QrCodeEncodingOptions
    {
        Width = 60,
        Height = 60
    }
};

Bitmap  barcodeBitmap = writer.Write(val);
...
```

}

But currently I found that function Write is missing in IBarcodeWriter in new ZXing version.

What is simplest way to print barcode to Bitmap in new ZXing version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `write` method appears to be missing in the interface `IBarcodeWriter`, but it is still present in the implementation class `BarcodeWriter`.

Try replacing the line

```cs
IBarcodeWriter writer = new BarcodeWriter
```

with either

```cs
BarcodeWriter writer = new BarcodeWriter
```

or

```cs
var writer = new BarcodeWriter
```

Answer (score 2):

The `Write` method was moved to the interface `IBarcodeWriter<TOutput>`. TOutput depends on the target platform and the specific BarcodeWriter implementation. In your case you should use `IBarcodeWriter<Bitmap> writer = new BarcodeWriter ...`. There are other implementations with different output types like `BarcodeWriterSvg` which implements `IBarcodeWriter<SvgImage>`.